# Compare data of current week against same week of previous years

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table that contains sales by stores & date.

```
-------------------------------------------
P_DATE       -    P_STORE -  P_SALES
-------------------------------------------
2019-02-05   -     S1     -   5000
2019-02-05   -     S2     -   9850
2018-06-17   -     S1     -   6980
2018-05-17   -     S2     -   6590
..
..
..
-------------------------------------------
```

I want to compare Sum of sales for each store of last 10 weeks of this year with same week of previous years.

I want a result like this :

```
---------------------------------------------------
Week   -   Store   -   Sales-2019   -   Sales2018
---------------------------------------------------
20     -   S1      -     2580       -     2430
20     -   S2      -     2580       -     2430
.
.
10     -   S1      -     5905       -     5214
10     -   S2      -     4789       -     6530
---------------------------------------------------
```

I'v tried this :

```
Select
[Week] = DATEPART(WEEK, E_Date),
[Store] = E_store
[Sales 2019] = Case when Year(P_date) = '2019' Then Sum (P_Sales)
[Sales 2018] = Case when Year(P_date) = '2018' Then Sum (P_Sales)

From
PIECE

Group by
DATEPART(WEEK, E_Date),
E_store
```

I need your help please.

Comment: "Same week in previous year" is ambiguous, because a year is not an exact number of weeks.  You need to define better what this means.

Comment: `[Sales 2019] =Sum ( Case when Year(P_date) = '2019' Then P_Sales END)`

Comment: @hamza.soufiane . . . You need to decide how "week 1" is defined.  Is it based on ISO standards?  Is it on the first Monday of the year?  How are weeks that include Jan 1 handled?

Comment: Are you sure about that, since you want the week to start on monday then the first week of the year should start on the first monday of the year?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```html
DECLARE @t TABLE (TransactionID INT, Week INT, Year INT, Amount MONEY)

INSERT INTO @t
(TransactionID, Week, Year, Amount)
VALUES
(1, 20, 2018, 50),
(2, 20, 2019, 20),
(3, 19, 2018, 35),
(4, 19, 2019, 40),
(5, 20, 2018, 70),
(6, 20, 2019, 80)

SELECT TOP 10 Week, [2018], [2019] FROM (SELECT Week, Year, SUM(Amount) As Amount FROM @t GROUP BY Week, Year) t
PIVOT  
(  
SUM(Amount)  
FOR Year IN ([2018], [2019])  
) sq
ORDER BY Week DESC
```

Comment: I used @t. So in the SELECT statement you should replace @t with PIECE in the subquery. You will also need to replace some of the columns naturally Year => YEAR(P_DATE), Week =>DATEPART(WEEK, E_Date), Amount => P_SALES...In other words:::

SELECT Week, [2018], [2019] FROM (SELECT DATEPART(WEEK, E_Date) As Week, YEAR(P_DATE) As Year, SUM(P_SALES) As Amount FROM PIECE GROUP BY DATEPART(WEEK, E_Date) , YEAR(P_DATE)) sales
PIVOT  
(  
SUM(Amount)  
FOR Year IN ([2018], [2019])  
) sq

Comment: Use a TOP 10 and order by. Naturally since you are explicitly mentioning the year you will only get 4 or weeks at the end of January. I've editing my code to reflect the requirement. Kindly accept my answer if this answers you question

Answer (score 0):

This script will consider 10 weeks including current week-

```
WITH wk_list (COMMON,DayMinus)
AS
(
SELECT 1,0 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,1 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,2 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,3 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,4 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,5 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,6 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,7 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,8 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,9
)
SELECT 
DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, P_DATE) WK,
P_STORE,
SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(P_DATE) = 2019 THEN P_SALES ELSE 0 END) SALES_2019,
SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(P_DATE) = 2018 THEN P_SALES ELSE 0 END) SALES_2018
FROM your_table
WHERE YEAR(P_DATE) IN (2019,2018)
AND DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, P_DATE) IN
(
    SELECT A.WKNUM-wk_list.DayMinus AS [WEEK NUMBER] 
    FROM wk_list
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT 1 AS COMMON,DATENAME(ISO_WEEK,GETDATE()) WKNUM
    ) A ON wk_list.COMMON = A.COMMON
)
GROUP BY DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, P_DATE),P_STORE
```

But if you want to exclude current week, just replace the following part in above script

```
, wk_list (COMMON,DayMinus)
AS
(
SELECT 1,1 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,2 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,3 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,4 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,5 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,6 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,7 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,8 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,9 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,10
)
```

Comment: No no no.... that's for only your reference. First table is craeted for a sample set of results. you just ignore that part and just start with....

WITH wk_list (COMMON,DayMinus)
AS
(
SELECT 1,0 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,1 UNION ALL.....

Comment: Ok, I have updated the first query. Now just adjust table and column names as per your table.